# How to bind multiple models to one ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

There are,for example, such classes:

```
class A(models.Model):
 id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
 mtm = models.ManyToManyField(B, C, D)

class B(models.Model):
 id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
class C(models.Model):
 id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
class D(models.Model):
 id = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
```

I know the implementation class of the field And the wrong, did so to make it clearer. You need to have that model And had a relationship ManyToMany with models b,C,D. How can this be done? Is there a special field?

Comment: Typically in that case you make a model that links instances together, like an `ABCD` model with `ForeignKey`s to all these models. In essence that is what a `ManyToManyField` does: it creates an implicit table in between.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the moment of writing, this is not possible. A [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) has a positional `to` argument with:

> ```
> class ManyToManyField(to, **options)
> ```
>
> A many-to-many relationship. Requires a positional argument: **the
>   class to which the model is related**, which works exactly the same as
>   it does for `ForeignKey`, including recursive and lazy relationships.

It would also create some confusion: what should the `mtm` return for `some_a.mtm.all()`? All related `B` objects? Tuples of `B`, `C` and `D` objects? What should be the name of the reversed relations?

This however does not mean that you can not *emulate* such relation. You can make a model that acts like a relation. In fact if you define a `ManyToManyField`, Django will create a table that stores data from this relation.

So we can define such model like:

```
class ABCDRel(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mtm')
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mtm')
    c = models.ForeignKey(C, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mtm')
    d = models.ForeignKey(D, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mtm')
```

We can then for example obtain a `QuerySet` of all related `ABCDRelation`s with:

```
some_a.mtm.all()
```

Or you can obtain a `QuerySet` of all related `B` objects through this relation with:

```
B.objects.filter(mtm__a=some_a)
```

The relation can contain extra data, but in essence thus stores "tuples" of how the objects of the models relate to each other.

This thus creates an entity-relation model that looks, more or less, like:

[image: Entity-relation model of this modeling]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and the time that you paid for his writing! I wanted to do that, but then I thought maybe there's another way I don't know. Thank you for helping me decide.

Comment: is this possible to do this 3 years later which is now?