# What is the best approach to bind multiple models to one ManyToMany field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm building a dashboard app that I would like the user to be able to customize. One of these customizable options would be the ability to choose different types of graphs to display data. My research into the best way to do this would be to use a ManyToMany field within my dashboard model; however, ManyToMany fields only allow 1 model--not multiple according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField):

> A many-to-many relationship. Requires a positional argument: the class to which the model is related, which works exactly the same as it does for ForeignKey, including recursive and lazy relationships.

More research brought me to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217937/how-to-bind-multiple-models-to-one-manytomanyfield) which recommended to create an intermediary 'ABCDRel' model that has foreign keys to each of the other models and emulate the behavior I'm looking for. The problem with that is I get this:[image] as compared to what I'm looking for in this: [image]

I use the admin page here to give a clearer picture of what I'm looking for.

Here's the intermediary I made according to the SO post above:

```
class GraphRelations(models.Model):
    heatmap = models.ForeignKey(Heatmap, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='m2m')
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='m2m')
```

And the ManyToMany field I have in my dashboard model:

```
graphs = models.ManyToManyField(GraphRelations)
```

The only other option I can think of would be to add a foreign key to each graph model I have and set an 'enabled' field within that graph model. However, that's not very extensible and I feel there are cleaner ways to do this.

Any pointers are helpful!